# Php ampersand seems not the same as mysql ampersand

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Mysql query is

```
SELECT `IdDP`, `DescriptionOrName` FROM `table` WHERE `DescriptionOrName` = ?;
```

Instead of `?` i use php value, received from another file (with ajax send value to current php file). If in Google Chrome click inspect, then i see such value `gr art & print`. And this value with ajax send to php file. But i get nothing from mysql.

If i use this

```
SELECT `IdDP`, `DescriptionOrName` FROM `table` WHERE `DescriptionOrName` = "gr art & print";
```

then all works.

All works also if i manually type `gr art & print` as php variable.

Compared from mysql selected `gr art & print` with php variable (received with ajax). Like

```
if( trim($val_select_ids_for_clicked_name['DescriptionOrName']) == trim(str_replace("&amp;","&",$_POST['data_to_send']['clicked_name'])) ){ 
echo 'mysql == to php<br/>';
} 
else{ 
echo 'mysql != to php<br/>';
}
```

And result is that `mysql != to php`

Seems finally found solution. For `?` must use php like `str_replace("&amp;","&",trim($_POST['data_to_send']['clicked_name']))`. In other words to replace  `&amp;` with `&`.

So does it mean that ajax (jquery) takes html value of `&` (html value is `&amp;`) and sends `&amp;` to php....? Are there more characters like this?

Comment: Ajax (jquery) should send the data as they are, unless you are doing some transformations with them. Technically it can do some urlencode, but that is automatically decoded by server before it's passed into `$_POST` variable. Your JS is probably reading the value from HTML code where the `&` is written as `&amp;` entity.

Comment: Yes, JS takes html value. Ok, seems situation is clear / solved.